# HTML5 Geolocation not working with GPS Only (Location Service Mode) on Android

Tags: android, cordova, gps

I have a problem with the HTML5 Geolocation.

I build an app and try to get user's location, i have opened the GPS, trying to set the Mode is GPS Only (because the code below works well with HighAccuracy Mode(use Wireless, Mobile Network, GPS)) but have no luck.

Here is my code :

if i set

```
enableHighAccuracy: false
```

the error will be : GPS Provider disabled

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: false, maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 150000 });
```

if i set

```
enableHighAccuracy: true
```

the error will be : Time out (because it runs out of 150000 ms)

I also use watchPosition instead of getCurrentPosition but no difference.

Please help me, because i cannot force the user to use HighAccuracy Mode.

Thank you !!

Comment: maybe this answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31391579/873650

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I was testing my app on a Nexus 4 device and it turns out the problem was that the device had no Sim Card. Meaning, no Cell data.

As it turns out, the GPS chip won't work without a Sim Card/Cellular Data. 
After testing it on another Android Device (with a working Sim Card) it worked fine.

@wdev is right, a regular GPS chip usually takes more than 10 minutes to get a fix on a geo-position. That is why most devices relay on A-GPS, which cuts the time down to a few seconds, but needs some sort of connection (Cellular or wifi).

If you're interested, [this Wikipedia article explains A-GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS)

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The GPS localisation takes a lot of time, especially indoors. And it is sometimes even impossible. You can use an application like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest&hl=fr to check if it's a problem with your code or the GPS fixing itself.

You have two options:

- ask the user to activate low accuracy
- use a very high maximumAge and hope that the user has been geolocated recently

Answer (score 0):

We do experience the following problem on Android phones:
- on some phones the api works just fine
- on some phones (Android 7.0) the behavior is that:

- if some other application using GPS is working in background at the moment we start Cordova based application: newly started Cordova geolocation seems to work just fine, no matter if high accuracy geolocation is enabled or 'just device' is enabled.
- if we start cordova application when GPS is eneabled in settings, but no other application is using geolocation right now (gps is not active at the moment of launching cordova app) - cordova application fails to retrieve position correctly. It does not seem to be able to activate gps device by it's own.
- even if cordova fails to activate gps - we do see cordova application appear in the list of applications that recently requested geolocation
- The clue is: if the geolocation 'pin' is visible on the taskbar before starting the cordova application everything will be fine. If not - it will not work.